# slither is not working on my linux environment

Tags: solidity, slither

```sh
slither test/TestUtils.sol
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mente/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 826, in main_impl
    ) = process_all(filename, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/home/mente/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 86, in process_all
    compilations = compile_all(target, **vars(args))
  File "/home/mente/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/crytic_compile/crytic_compile.py", line 637, in compile_all
    compilations.append(CryticCompile(target, **kwargs))
  File "/home/mente/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/crytic_compile/crytic_compile.py", line 117, in init
    self._compile(**kwargs)
  File "/home/mente/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/crytic_compile/crytic_compile.py", line 548, in _compile
    self._platform.compile(self, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mente/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/crytic_compile/platform/solc.py", line 154, in compile
    targets_json = _get_targets_json(compilation_unit, self._target, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mente/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/crytic_compile/platform/solc.py", line 276, in _get_targets_json
    return _run_solc(
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of this error is that the version of the Crytic Compile library installed on your system is incompatible with the version of Python you're using. The error message mentions that Python 3.10 is being used, but the latest version of Crytic Compile only supports Python 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8.

To resolve this issue, you could try uninstalling the current version of Crytic Compile and installing a compatible version. You can check the supported Python versions for the latest version of Crytic Compile on its GitHub page: https://github.com/crytic/crytic-compile

Once you have a compatible version of Crytic Compile installed, you should be able to use Slither to analyze your contracts without encountering this error. It's also a good idea to double-check that all of the other dependencies for Slither are installed and up-to-date, as this can sometimes cause similar issues.